# SMART: UltraDMA selected jumps back and forth between 5 and 6

Tags: ssd, sata, smart, dma

Every time I am viewing SMART-Data of my SATA SSD (Samsung 870 EVO 2TB) with Disk Checkup software I see different value of "UltraDMA selected" parameter. It is times 5 times 6. May be it changes from boot to boot.

Is it serious? I do not notice any change in SSD performance.

[image: SMART parameters]

Comment: UltraDMA was (as far as I knew) a thing from before SATA, though it may be that the logical protocol is still used underneath the Serial ATA transfers. If you get anywhere above 200MB/s then UltraDMA mode is likely irrelevant.

Comment: Actual selected speed is result of negotiation between host and drive, some noisy connector/connection may disrupt it.